# Expected HTTP status code for an action on a disabled resource

Tags: rest, http, api-design

What would the expected/proper HTTP status code on an action given the following:

- the request syntax is correct (eliminates `400`)
- user is authenticated (eliminates `401`)
- user is authorized to perform the action (eliminates `403`)
- location/resource exists (eliminates `404`)
- method is implemented (eliminates `501`)
- no server error (eliminates `5xx`)

The resource is currently disabled thus preventing the action from completing with the expected result. The user has the ability to change the state of the resource and retry the same request. Information on the why the resource could not do what was asked would be included in the response body.

My thought is that `409 Conflict` would be the best response as user could potentially change the state of the resource and resubmit the request, but maybe there's something better out there to indicate *"This method is generally allowed by you, but the resource is currently in a state that prevents it from completing as expected."*

Comment: Can you perhaps explain a bit more in which way the resource is "disabled?" IMHO 409 indicates a conflict in the *presentation* while this is a discussion largely regarding the *semantics*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like that is the Internet's consensus, and I see nothing better [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml). [See here for another similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141951/invalid-operation-status-code-in-a-hateoas-rest-api)

**409**

> This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.
> [Source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)

This is then followed up

> Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request.  For
> example, if versioning were being used and the representation being
> PUT included changes to a resource that conflict with those made by
> an earlier (third-party) request

That seems more like the entity shifted underneath the client while the client constructed a call, perhaps the assumption is the client asks for the allowed actions, before making the call(s). If you implemented that, I would say 409 is perfectly valid for your API since you provide the ability for clients to make *only* valid requests, unless someone else changes the entity.

Clearly you should be consistent, and document the response codes and their usage.

Comment: I think a 409 indicates that a change in the request is necessary / possible for it to be successful. However, a deactivated resource cannot be processed successfully under any circumstances. Think 403 fits better

Comment: A 410 Gone would still be interesting, but as the definition suggests:
"...indicates that access to the target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be permanent...If you don't know whether this condition is temporary or permanent, a 404 status code should be used instead." => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410

Answer (score 3):

According to RFC 4918 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2), you could use code 422 (Unprocessable Entity) to handle situations like it.

> 422 Unprocessable Entity
>
> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The 409 seems the best fit, this is what http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html says:

> This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict. Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be possible and is not required.

Comment: RFC2616 is out of date. Please refer to RFC 7230-7235.

Comment: @EricStein is there a different code in RFC 7230-7235 or is this just for reference?

Comment: @SamJakob Just for reference. The codes have not changed.